# ASP.NET dropdown list value name change

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Hello I have this code for user role section but I wanted to change display names on role.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Roles, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ObjList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.rolelist, new { id = "ddlLocations", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

So how can I show value of role 1 as ADMIN,
                           role2 as CLIENT

Answer (score 0):

You should fill the `ViewBag` with `SelectListItem` in your controller like this :

```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var ObjList = new List<SelectListItem>()
       {
           new SelectListItem { Text = "ADMIN", Value = "1" },
           new SelectListItem { Text = "CLIENT", Value = "2" },
       };

       ViewBag.rolelist= ObjList;

       return View();
    }
```

In View :

```
@Html.DropDownList("ObjList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.rolelist, new { id = "ddlLocations", @class = "form-control" })
```